# Video streaming using Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I have to capture video from my web-cam and I have to transmit the video using tcp using different codecs and containers using gstreamer.
I am using the following command
in server:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \
    ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc \
    ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

in client:

```
gst-launch tcpclientsrc host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 \
    ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

For this I am getting the output. Now I want to transfer the video in some other codecs and containers. So what are the commands?

Comment: Which other codecs and container formats do you want? Also check the docs, it basically all works the same just with different element names.

Comment: Also consider using gstreamer-1.X

Comment: I want to use containers like avi,ogg,webm,mp4 etc..

Comment: Which of these? The element names are different depending on the container format, and every container format also has support for a different set of codecs.
Which codecs should be used?

Also not all container formats can be streamed, e.g. MP4 can't be live streamed. You can only stream it after the writing has finished.

Comment: Googled "gstreamer cheat sheet" for you: http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Gstreamer_cheat_sheet